# Dynamic binding to function depending on arguments in C++

Tags: c++, function, dynamic, virtual

I was expecting the assignment operator to be dynamically bound depending on the argument type:

```
struct NumberObject;
struct NumberString;

struct DataType
{
    virtual void operator=(DataType& rhs) {};
    virtual void operator=(NumberString& rhs) {};
};
struct NumberObject : DataType
{
    double data = 7;
    void operator=(DataType& rhs)  override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from DataType\n"; 
// The assignment operator that's called is this one. I was hoping it would be the one below.
    }
    void operator=(NumberString& rhs) override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from NumberString\n";
    }
};
struct NumberString : DataType
{
    std::string data = "7";
    void operator=(NumberString& rhs) override{};
};


int main()
{
    DataType *pDataType1, *pDataType2;
    pDataType1 = new NumberObject;
    pDataType2 = new NumberString;
    *pDataType1 = *pDataType2;   // Both pointers are to DataType, I was hoping that the assignment operator taking 
                            // NumberString as the right hand side would be called


    return 0;
}
```

From this I guess that C++ can't dynamically bind functions based on the argument type. The dynamic binding only happens when calling a function directly through an object. So I thought I could do this, but it does seem like a roundabout way:

```
struct NumberObject : DataType
{
    double data = 7;
    void operator=(DataType& rhs)  override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from DataType\n";
        rhs.assignTo(*this);
    }
    void operator=(NumberString& rhs) override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from NumberString\n";
    }
};
struct NumberString : DataType
{
    std::string data = "7";
    void assignTo(NumberObject& lhs) override 
    {// Provided the base class had this
        lhs.data = atof(this->data.c_str());
    }

    void operator=(NumberString& rhs) override{};
};
```

This seems like a hack, and seeing as though the language is capable of dynamic binding, isn't this something it could do easily? Is it a weakness of the language? Or does nobody care about it?

Comment: I haven't wrote cpp in a while, but I'm glad I haven't. It really isn't the nicest of languages and learning all its quirks takes a long time.....

One solution might be to just always expect a string. Then you'd simply have to convert the number being passed to a string..... 

Alternatively, maybe use templating? That'd be better than having two separate definitions for otherwise the same classes.

Comment: You have run into the double dispatch problem. Read up on the subject. Here's a place to get started. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch.

Comment: @Sahu Reading it now. I love this language so much but it gets so frustrating sometimes that I feel like doing everything myself with void pointers

Comment: c++ needs to resolve types at compile-time so it knows what the type of the expression is before it generates code.  As such, it uses the static type of the variables, not the dynamic type, and it could be called a "limitation" of the language, or you could call it the way statically typed languges behave.  As suggested, you need the double dispatch idiom.

Comment: @Zebra - It gets frustrating when you try to fight the language. :-) Dynamic binding is what happens for virtual functions, depending on the left hand side of the assignment. The type of right hand side is here used for overload resolution. That uses static types, as always. To get a "double virtual" call you need to use the [Double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C.2B.2B) which in C++ really *is* implemented as two separate virtual calls, one for each party involved.

Comment: So it comes down to either doing a couple of if checks or dynamic casts for the different types, or another dynamic vtable lookup. They say that C and C++ are faster than the other "higher level" languages, I wonder if this holds true even with all the fancy bells and whistles, like double dynamic dispatch and so on. The way C++ is changing is incredible, now people say stuff like never use raw pointers, don't use new, don't use c arrays etc.

Comment: You have ran into a problem which is at least 50 years old, and has very little to do with specific programming languages. If it had a satisfactory solution,  C++ would probably adopt it by now. It doesn't, and it haven't. Life sucks.

Comment: *"never use raw pointers, don't use new, don't use c arrays"*: it is raw **owning** pointer which are bad, there are legit usage of pointer. prefer `make_unique`/`make_shared` over `new` (so smart ptr over raw owning pointer). `std::array` is a nice replacement to C-array. So except for `shared_ptr`, there are no overhead for the replacement (and the "overhead" of `shared_ptr` is because it add new functionalities which you would pay in different way to have it if done manually anyway).

Answer (score 0):

With double dispatching, it would be:

```
struct NumberObject;
struct NumberString;

struct DataType
{
    virtual ~DataType() = default;
    virtual void operator=(const DataType&) = 0;
    virtual void assignTo(NumberObject&) const = 0;
    virtual void assignTo(NumberString&) const = 0;
};

struct NumberObject : DataType
{
    double data = 7;
    void operator=(const DataType& rhs) override { rhs.assignTo(*this); }

    void assignTo(NumberObject& rhs) const override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from NumberObject\n"; 
    }
    void assignTo(NumberString& rhs) const override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from NumberObject\n";
    }
};

struct NumberString : DataType
{
    std::string data = "7";
    void operator=(const DataType& rhs) override { rhs.assignTo(*this); }

    void assignTo(NumberObject& rhs) const override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from NumberString\n"; 
    }
    void assignTo(NumberString& rhs) const override
    {
        std::cout << "Copying from NumberString\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/U4bwew)